# Return error with HttpEntity in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I have this piece of code:

```
 public HttpEntity<byte[]> getReport(){
        WebController.LOGGER.info("Requested report");

        try {
            byte[] reportData= reportService.getReport();
            return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(reportData);
        } catch (ReportGenerationException e) {
            //WHAT DO I RETURN HERE?
        }
    }
```

I want to return a 500 error when the report can not be generated, but HttpEntity does not allow me to set the HTTP status code. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ResponseEntity (child of HttpEntity)  to set the HTTP status codes.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getReport(){
    WebController.LOGGER.info("Requested report");

    try {
        byte[] reportData= reportService.getReport();
        return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(reportData);
    } catch (ReportGenerationException e) {
        //WHAT DO I RETURN HERE?
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that, HttpEntity is not a ResponseEntity. I can, however, do it the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: ResponseEntity extends HttpEntity. So can't you just upcast?

Comment: I know this is a museum, but in the try you should be doing return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, HttpStatus.OK); instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create next exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class ReportInternalException extends RuntimeException {
    public ReportInternalException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And throw it in your catch block:

```
...    
} catch (ReportGenerationException e) {
       throw new ReportInternalException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this?

```
return new ResponseEntity<Exception>(e,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```